# PLinq on single CORE processor

Tags: c#, .net, plinq

Will the performance of PLINQ be any different from a normal LINQ query when you have only a single CORE processor assuming that you are querying a collection having one million records.

I understand that PLINQ works very good on multicore processors. Just wanted to understand how it behaves on a single CORE processor.

Comment: The only way to measure threading performance is: measure on your specific scenario. It is too complex to generalise. However: if you are querying entirely locally (no IO overheads etc), then: it can't really be any *faster* on a single core. The question, then, is: is it any *slower*. All I can suggest there is: test it. But frankly: it is almost 2013 - who has a single core without even HT for 2 virtual cores? (or is this for use on something like ARM, like a raspberry pi?)

Answer (score 3):

According to Joe Duffy and Ed Essey: "on a single-processor machine, the overhead of PLINQ is typically so small that you won't notice a difference."

From [Running Queries On Multi-Core Processors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx)